# PHP C or store sql query in array

Tags: php, sql

I have a query that gets a number of cols off my database

```
$searchResults = mysql_query("SELECT customerRefId, seekingAddressSuburb, 
  seekingAddressPostcode, seekingAddressState FROM customer_seeking");
```

Then I use the data to display a HTML table

```
?>
<table border="1">
<th>Customer Ref ID</th>
<th>Suburb</th>
<th>State</th>
<th>Postcode</th>
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($searchResults))
{
echo"<tr><td>$row[customerRefId]</td><td>$row[seekingAddressSuburb]</td><td>$row[seekingAddressPostcode]</td><td>$row[seekingAddressState]</td></tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

What I need to do next is have another query as per below, but instead of hard coding `9,10` I want to use the `$row[customerRefId]` for the `IN ()`

Should I use `mysql_data_seek($searchResults,0);` to retun to the top of the sql results or should I build an arrary?

```
$searchResults2 = mysql_query("SELECT customerRefId, firstName, lastName, email, phone, mobile FROM customer_contact WHERE customerRefId IN (9,10)");
```

Comment: YES! Keep using `mysql_`. In the meantime, may I ask what your website's URL is?

Comment: I think storing in an array would be a better choice, as it will be cheaper, faster and efficient to use an in memory data structure compared to fetching it again from database(which might require a disk I/O).

Comment: In general, I'd try to avoid having your web app switch control from PHP to the database, back to PHP, back to the database, back to PHP. Also, please take @ColeJohnson's suggestion above and use _something_ else besides raw `mysql_` calls to access your database. Maybe use PDO. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: if you used the same result set for MySQL then its better to use mysql_data_seek, mysql already used memory and placed the whole result for you, no need to duplicate into array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly as everyone is saying in the comments mysql_* functions are deprecated and you need to switch to mysqli.

To solve your problem what you need is a `JOIN`.  With a `JOIN` you can get data from both tables combined. Here's an example:

```
SELECT 
    customerRefId,
    seekingAddressSuburb, 
    seekingAddressPostcode, 
    seekingAddressState,
    firstName,
    lastName,
    email,
    phone,
    mobile
FROM 
    customer_seeking cs
LEFT JOIN
    customer_contact cc ON cc.customerRefId = cs.customerRefId
```

Every time you loop through a row you will have all the data at once!